# Database connection not working when everything is correct

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
/*

db_connect.php

*/
$config = include_once("site_config.php");
$mysqliConnection = mysqli_connect($config['db_host'], $config['db_user'], $config['db_pass'], $config['db_name']);
?>

<?php
return array(
"db_host" => "test",
"db_user" => "cozycow",
"db_pass" => "",
"db_name" => "tradesite",
"s_title" => "Trade site",
"s_logo" => ".jpg"
);
?>
```

It throws up the error

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
>   ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in
>   /usr/www/cozycow/public/trade/includes/db_connect.php on line 8

Comment: so show us your `site_config.php` contents

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for posting. Would you please read the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) entry on writing questions.  Your title could be worded better to be more informative. Also, please introducing the code to make your post more readable.

Comment: It's the return array

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your username or password is incorrect. Can you access your database by using database management software such as phpMyAdmin using the same username and password?

Comment: I blurred the user and pass out and I had the correct stuff in there.

Comment: I have just recreated your issue. Your error code `Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045)` appears when I created a user with password but I don't use that password in my database connection. You should double-check if your user is assigned with a password.